# How to implement Reconciliation concept in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a string to my list and I have a `CounterComponent` that works separately from `HelloWordComponent`, I set 1 for 'Microsoft', 2 for 'FaceBook' and 3 for 'React'; when I add 'yahoo' to first of the list, Counter for 'yahoo' set to 1 and react turns to 0.

I know I have to use unique key and I think `{name}` is qualified, but I don't know where to use `key = {name}` exactly?

```js
class HelloWordComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.name}</div>
  }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()

        this.onPlusClick = this.onPlusClick.bind(this)

         this.state = {count : 0}
    }

    onPlusClick(){
        this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count + 1}))
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            {this.state.count}
            <button onClick = {this.onPlusClick}>+</button>
        </div>
    }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()

    this.addName = this.addName.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      name: "Sara",
      list:['Microsoft', 'FaceBook', 'React']
    }

  }

  addName(){
    this.setState(prevState =>({list: ['Yahoo', ...prevState.list]}))
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div >
      {this.state.name}

      {this.state.list.map(name =>{
        return <div>
          <HelloWordComponent key = {name} name = {name}/>
          <Counter/>
          </div>
      })}

      <br/>
      <button onClick= {this.addName}>add a Name</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"> </div>
```

Comment: would you mind if you give me some explain?

Comment: What is _Counter_ ?

Comment: @SultanH. I added Counter Component to my question.

Comment: What about having the `counter` value attached to each item from the `list` in your state? would that be ok? it'll still be modifiable via _Counter_ component, but we'll need to store the count in the main component instead, then pass it to the _Counter_ as a _prop_.

Comment: I've try this too, and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the right solution of my problem, I have to set unique key (`key = {name}`) in my **parent root element** `<div key = {name}>` so the render method change to:

```
render(){
    return (
    <div >
      {this.state.name}

      {this.state.list.map(name =>{
        return <div key = {name}>
          <HelloWordComponent name = {name}/>
          <Counter/>
          </div>
      })}
```

Comment: As merhab says it should go on the parent element in the map loop.